# Symfony3 illegal name and forbidden char in general

Tags: forms, utf-8, symfony

I would like to use any kind of ***char like "é" or "è"*** or ***even the space*** for most of my *form's names or **labels***.
The probleme is that I get each time a:

> The name "Téléphone" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

The problem is that my website is in ***French***, and therefore I need to use those kind of characters.
Is there a way to use encoding like utf-8 for exemple?

---

EDIT:

I edit with an other case that occur with space and accents but slitely different than the previous one.
A code that cause me problem with the chars:

```
$testForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('Nom', TextType::class)
    ->add('Description', TextType::class);

$i = 2;
foreach ($listWidget as $key => $widget)
{
    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $widget->getNom());
    $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i++, FormType::class, null); 
    $formBuilder
        ->add($name, ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Créer' => 'C',
            'Afficher' => 'R',
            'Modifier' => 'U',
            'Supprimer' => 'D'),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_label' => $widget->getNom()));
    $testForm->add($formBuilder);
}
$testForm->add('send', SubmitType::class);
$profilForm = $testForm->getForm();
```

I get this error:

> PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "string" while trying to traverse path "Contacts Client" at property "Contacts Client".

"Contact Client" is one of the $widget names and might get accents.

---

EDIT:
'choice_label' error is totaly normal, I had to use the 'label' option.

Comment: You're givin' the name of a form component! You cant use those characters, the name of the field should be : telephone  . In the label you can put what you want ! Please provide your form builder

Comment: Your comment was right, I did the change on my side. My problem still existe with an other form so I edited. If needed I'll post a new question.

Comment: The error was in fact way different so I never mind. Thanks again.